# Linear Tranformations

Tags: linear-algebra

[image]

Hello, everyone. I'm having trouble solving this problem. I tried row reducing and find that the 3rd row can be reduced to only zeroes. Which leaves two pivots and two free variables, but the problem asks for a vector in $R^4$ and I think row reducing doesn't really help me here. Anyone have ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to find the *kernel* of $A$.

Let's look at a $3 \times 2$ case.  Say your RREF is $$\left[\begin{array}{ccc|c}1 & 2 & 0 & 0\\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\end{array}\right]$$

What does this mean?  Well let's rewrite the scalar equations that this augmented matrix represents.  They are $\begin{cases} x+2y=0 \\ z=0 \\ 0=0\end{cases}$.  The last equation doesn't tell us anything.  But the second tells us that $z$ *must* be zero for this set of equations to be consistent.  The first equation tells us that there is a relationship between $x$ and $y$.

What we'd like to do here is look at which columns of our matrix *don't* contain a pivot (a leading $1$).  That's the second column in this case.  So we want to parametrize our space by letting $y$ (the second variable) equal some arbitrary constant: say $y=t$.  Then we can see that $x=-2t$.

So all vectors which satisfy our homogeneous set of equations -- i.e. the kernel of this matrix -- have the form $(x,y,z) = (-2t,t,0)=t(-2,1,0)$.  So *every* scalar multiple of the vector $(-2,1,0)$ solves this system.

Now why don't you see if you can figure out your problem.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** The rref of the matrix $A$ is:
$$S=\left[\begin{array}{rrrr}1   &  0  & -16 &  -16\\
     0  &   1   & -5  &  -3\\
     0   &  0    & 0   &  0\end{array}\right]$$
You have to find two vectors  in the linear subspace $Null(A)=\{x\in\mathbb{R}^4\:|\: Ax=0\}$.
But the solutions of the linear system $Ax=0$ coincides with those of the system $Sx=0$.

Solving the system $Sx=0$ you can choose two solutions, i.e. two vectors as it is required.